# How to get tempName in yii2 UploadedFile Object?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have made uploads file module in yii2 with angularJs.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="questionData.excel_file" name="excel_file" ngf-max-size="20MB" required/>
```

**PHP:**

```
$model->excel_file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'excel_file');
print "<pre>";
print_r($model->excel_file);
print "</pre>";
exit;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
yii\web\UploadedFile Object
(
    [name] => question.xls
    [tempName] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpF66E.tmp
    [type] => application/vnd.ms-excel
    [size] => 20480
    [error] => 0
)
```

How to get **tempName** in Yii2 UploadedFile Object

I have get tempName using following method **$model->excel_file->tempName;**. But, return error

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: `$tempName` is public property. You can get it `$model->excel_file->tempName`
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html

Comment: But, I have found this error "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: How are you using `$model->excel_file->tempName`? Add example, please.

Comment: Hi @BharatChauhan :  At least Reply To The Answer Given Below *Ehsaan Hoga*

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'excel_file');
$image->tempName;
```

Or

```
$model->excel_file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'excel_file');
$model->excel_file->tempName;
```

It will work. That's For Sure.

Answer (score 0):

As I and @Nana Partykar already say: `$tempName` is public property. You can get it

```
$model->excel_file->tempName
```

If you get an error **Trying to get property of non-object**, it means that

```
$model->excel_file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'excel_file');
```

returns `null`.

Please, check the documentation page [yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html](http://yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html)